# Supervised Learning Quiz website?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

What are some good websites which  provide quiz questions on supervised learning and machine learning in general?
I have a quiz coming up and I would like to be prepared for it.

Comment: You can take the this Machine learning course in Edx. Take a look at the subjects: https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:UCSanDiegoX+DSE220x+1T2019a/course/

Comment: Of many sources, try a few on Analytics Vidhya: [a](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/04/40-questions-test-data-scientist-machine-learning-solution-skillpower-machine-learning-datafest-2017/), [b](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/tag/machine-learning-interview-questions/)

Comment: one can use kaggle course also. https://www.kaggle.com/learn/overview

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which Quiz you are talking about. But these might help.

This is for AWS Machine learning exam:

https://d1.awsstatic.com/training-and-certification/docs-ml/AWS%20Certified%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Specialty_Sample%20Questions.pdf

And this is for Microsoft Azure Machine Learning exam:

https://www.itexams.com/exam/70-774

Take a look.